# How to show Google Map directions in Blackberry?

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I have source and destination latitude and longitude values, and wish to display a Google map showing the route using the Blackberry browser field. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

yes, as long as you can make http requests: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html

there are several APIs from Google Maps you could try: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/